# Copy users from Online to On-Premise SharePoint

Tags: migration, groups, user, move

I have a strange situation. I accidentally deleted some groups from a SharePoint on premise site collection. I have a backup of those groups and users in an online site.

I have googled a lot but haven't found out a solution where i can copy all the Users and Groups from Online site collection to On Premise site collection.

I have Metalogix tool but not sure if its possible on the tool.

> Metalogix: The user mapping has to be done but not sure how to do that mapping, i have tried using source and target users with Source as `something@someoneOnline.com` and target as 
>   i:0#.w|sm\st33442 to no avail. Then i have also tried using i:0#.f|membership| in front of the online IDs but the tool does not recognize.

Wanted to know if there is a way to do this reverse migration.

Any response is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted SharePoint group in on premise and if you know the name of the groups and permission level associated with it then you can get it back with all the users in it.May I know if you have resolved this issue or still looking for an answer.I have a solution for you.You may not need to restore from backup or from SharePoint online.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, Yes the issue is resolved, i had to restore the backup of this site to another one and then had to do migration of users and groups. But this is still a mystery that will our tools be able to migrate reverse i.e. from Online to On Premise. Do we have any tool  or is there any way out.

Comment: Hi Sree, You don't need any tool to restore back group and users even if it is deleted accidentally or intentionally.All you need is to remember group name and permission level associated with the group. To do so follow these steps:  go to site settings>site permissions>grant permissions>type in deleted group name eg "testgroup">click show options to select permission level>share. this will create a same group with all existing users in it.All you need to know is group name and permission level.

Comment: actually when i checked in the site collection the group was deleted. Does it mean that even if we delete any group still if we try to add that it will be present?

Comment: Hi Sree,                                                                                                           Yes.If you type in deleted group name,it people picker will highlight you same group name.All you need to do is select it and then associate it with same permission level as earlier.If you have testing environment then you can give a try.